# Using sequences for every row in a sql-server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sequence

We have a table *Property* in our database containing a counter in every row stored in the *NextVoucherNumber* integer column. There are about 2000 rows there.

```
  ID  ... {other columns} ... NextVoucherNumber
-----------------------------------------------
   1                                        112
   2                                         34
   3                                         29
   4                                       9456
....                                       ....   
2000                                        233
```

We have an issue with a concurrent access to the table.
To improve the performance we would like to extract those columns to a **separate table** *PropertyVoucherNumbers* with a 1:1 relation between the rows.

```
  ID   NextVoucherNumber
------------------------
   1                 112
   2                  34
   3                  29
   4                9456
....                ....   
2000                 233
```

Alternatively, we could maintain **sequences for every row**.
Seq_VoucherNumber_1, Seq_VoucherNumber_2, ... Seq_VoucherNumber_2000.
Looks like the same triggers just a little dynamic SQL there.

Could you please describe what the problems we will face using the second solution?

Can you suggest any better solution?

Comment: Can you take a step back and tell us _how_ the first table is being used (and also show us the table definition)?  Maybe what you are missing is just an appropriate index somewhere.

Comment: I'm afraid the main problem of blocking is an opened transaction left by an ORM for long. It is a bug there but nobody will fix it https://www.telerik.com/data-access-sunsetting

Comment: The table contains of 132 columns. It used to describe a property in our property management system. Every property has it's own accounting with it's vouchers numeration.

Comment: Please rollback the stuff you just dumped into your question.  You will attract downvotes if you leave your question in this state.

Comment: This is almost a textbook example of an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/). How about we try to help you fix the blocking issue?

Comment: My question was: is it a good idea to maintain 2000 'native' sequences instead of keeping them in a table?

The answer is obvious about one sequence. The question about 2000.

Comment: This smells like bad design to me. I don't pretend to know your business needs but having 2000 different sequences is probably not the droids you are looking for.   What if your table grows to 5000 records? You should probably describe in more details why do you think you need a different sequence object for each record, so that we can help you come up with a reasonable solution.

Comment: So, it is a bad idea what ever I need it for. Thanks.